View is not expanding with rows untill resize workbench
I have RCP plugin app, which has a "package view" with tree nodes, a "view1" which would sit in the same area as a problems view would in the java perspective, but on startup shows column headings but packed, when I double click a node in the package explorer view , it loads the data in "view1" (which is a Tableviewer) with a refresh, but it does not show it until I use my mouse to resize the workbench. How do I show "view1" with an expanded table of rows of data I have?
 To give an example
Class View1 extends ViewPart{
    TableViewer viewer ;
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
       viewer = new TableViewer(parent); 
       // create columns
       // set Header and Lines to be visible  
       // etc
       //don't assign content provider

    }

    public void refresh() {
      if (contentprovider = null){
         //set contentprovider
         viewer.setinput();
         viewer.refresh();

      }  
    }

}


thanks in advance,
Jemrug
       

As a complete guess you may need to call layout on the main Composite for the view

Your code is broken, it needs to be viewer = new TableViewer(parent);. See Javadoc and JFace Snippets.

That was just an example , yes I understand otherwise you will have huge listing , i was just showing some code so that it is easier to describe what I had written. So where would I use the call to the layout on the main composite( which is the parent I'm guessing)? layout  do you mean layout manager @greg?

Please verify that your minimal reproducible example is complete and compiles before you post it (which is still not the case). In your example, calling layout would be parent.layout();.

Guys it worked , I can't for some reason mark this question as answered. parent.layout() did the trick.
